# How to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}=e^{x}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have a problem:

$E(x)=e^x$, $L(x)=\ln (x)$, $E^{-1}(x)=L(x)$.

> Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}=e^{x}$

Hint: use $f(t)=\ln (1+xt)$ and look at $f'(0), x\neq 0$.

I found out that $f'(0)=x$, so I can put it in $e^{f'(0)}$, but I don't know how it can help me. Please, can anyone here help me with this problem or give me a link to a good proof. I'm desperate.

Comment: You should fix $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ and not $\lim_{x\to\infty}$.

Comment: Yes, it was helpful, but I hope that there is somebody here that knows if I can use f(t) in a way that links all the functions given in a good way. But thx :)

Comment: I remember that when I started study maths at uni in my first year course of Calculus (or Analysis) that was our definition of exponential function. Then it was a real mess to prove that $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$. If you are interested the only book that I know that uses this definition is by Miranda (and it is in Italian, sorry!).

Comment: @netwon1227 See my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

you already have  $f'(0) = x$ for $f(x) = \ln(1+xt)$ if we write the definition of $$  x = f'(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1/n) - f(0)}{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\ln(1 + x/n)\right) =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\ln((1+x/n)^n$$

exponentiating the equality gives you $$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n. $$

Comment: My brain might be very slow, but how do you go between these steps? f'(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1/n) - f(0)}{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}n\left(\ln(1 + x/n)\right)

\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1/n) - f(0)}{1/n} is this the definition of the derivative?

Comment: @netwon1227, the definition  $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}.$  now choose $h = \frac 1n$ and let $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\ln$ is continuous, so show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln((1+\frac xn)^n) = x$$
Where
$$\ln((1+\frac xn)^n) = n\ln(1+\frac xn) = \frac{f(\frac1n)-f(0)}{\frac1n} \to f'(0) = x$$
By the definition of the derivative.